# How to implement Linecollection to dataframe to color one line with different color?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, line-plot

I need to plot subplots with different colored lines according to the condition.
For this purpose, I try to use LineCollection. But with my data, I receive errors and can not find a way how to use it with my data. I stack with this stack, can someone give me a hint on how to make it work.

My data looks next:

```
age_gps_data ref_station_id river_km    
1.0     2421.0          667.5144925407869   
0.5     2421.0          667.5144592533758   
1.0     2421.0          667.5144249505418   
0.5     2421.0          667.5143958295257   
1.0     2421.0          667.5143629441299   
0.5     2421.0          667.5143266152246   
1.0     2.0     667.5142970594003   
0.5     2.0     667.5142580343961   
1.0     2.0     667.5142211073334   
0.5     2.0     667.5141878187346
```

I try this solution, but I have an error:

```
 filename = "G:\\ais_evaluation\\track_AIS_2route.csv"
 df2 = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=';')

 segments = []
 color = np.zeros(shape=(10,4))
 x = df2['river_km'].tolist()
 y = df2['age_gps_data'].tolist()

 i = 0
 z = df2.ref_station_id

 for x1, y1, x2, y2 in zip(x, x[1:], y, y[1:]):

    if z == 2.0:
       color[i] = colors.to_rgba('Crimson')
    else:
        color[i] = colors.to_rgba('slategray')
    segments.append([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])
    i += 1 

 lc = mc.LineCollection(segments, colors=color, linewidths=2)
 fig, ax = pl.subplots()
 ax.add_collection(lc)
 ax.autoscale()
 ax.margins(0.1)
 pl.show()
```

I have this error:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(
```

How should I improve this code to achieve line river_km vs age_gps_data with different colors according to parameter ref_station_id ?
I am new in python and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem comes from the line `if z == 2.0:`. Here z is a pandas Series `df2.ref_station_id`) and so it cannot be equal to 2.0.

I don't follow exactly the logic of your code so I cannot for sure tell you what to do, but it looks like you need to iterate through the values of `z` at the same time as `x` and `y` and test whether the subsequent values of `z` and not `z` itself, equals 2.0

for example:

```
for x1, y1, x2, y2, z0 in zip(x, x[1:], y, y[1:], z):
    if z0 == 2.0:
    (...)
```

**EDIT** Here is a whole functionning code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
from matplotlib import collections as mc
from io import StringIO

d = """age_gps_data ref_station_id river_km    
1.0     2421.0          667.5144925407869   
0.5     2421.0          667.5144592533758   
1.0     2421.0          667.5144249505418   
0.5     2421.0          667.5143958295257   
1.0     2421.0          667.5143629441299   
0.5     2421.0          667.5143266152246   
1.0     2.0     667.5142970594003   
0.5     2.0     667.5142580343961   
1.0     2.0     667.5142211073334   
0.5     2.0     667.5141878187346   
"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), delimiter='\\s+')

segments = []
color = np.zeros(shape=(10,4))
x = df2['river_km'].tolist()
y = df2['age_gps_data'].tolist()

i = 0
z = df2.ref_station_id

for x1, y1, x2, y2, z0 in zip(x, y, x[1:], y[1:], z):
    if z0 == 2.0:
        color[i] = colors.to_rgba('Crimson')
    else:
        color[i] = colors.to_rgba('slategray')
    segments.append([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])
    i += 1 

lc = mc.LineCollection(segments, colors=color, linewidths=2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I try your suggestion, and I have this error: `color[i] =colors.to_rgba('slategray')

IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10 `

Comment: your `color` array is too small. You have set it to be 10 elements long, but it needs to be as long as the number of lines in your file.

Comment: I checked `(len(segments)) ` it has 10 segments

Comment: And also I checked the color list it has the only grey color. But in the dataframe I should have 2 colors

Comment: The code seem to work on my machine, I inverted some stuff in the `zip()` of you for loop because I couldn't figure out what you were doing, but that doesnt change much. I posted a full code with output above